# Chrome OS Kiosk Mode not detecting the App I created

Tags: web-applications, google-chrome-os

**Question no longer relevant. Answers may not be verified**

I have created a App in the Chrome Web Store and made it private within the company that I wrote it for. It's primary purpose is to be used as a Kiosk App in a couple of Chromebooks that we purchased for a store.

Nearly everything is working well, except the app, after installed, does not have an ID that is valid in "Manage kiosk applications." It also does not show in chrome://extensions, though it does show up in "Apps Developer Tool." It also does enable Kiosk settings, it just isn't valid for use. Entering either the App ID taken from Apps Developer Tool or the store url report an error "... Invalid application."

Disable kiosk applications is not enabled in chrome://flags, and I have checked that the feature is working by testing using the ID from another app.

Manifest below:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "SoCal Rafting Kiosk",
"description":"SoCal Rafting",
"version": "1.3",
"kiosk_enabled": true,
"icons": { "128": "128.png" },
"app": {
    "urls": [
        "http://www.socalrafting.com/"
    ],
    "launch": {
        "web_url": "http://www.socalrafting.com/"
    }
},
"icons": {
    "128": "128.png"
}
```

}

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is this Google Chrome (Hosted) App invalid for Kiosk mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640198/why-is-this-google-chrome-hosted-app-invalid-for-kiosk-mode)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to you manifest:

```
"kiosk_enabled": true
```

[Via Francois Beaufort](https://plus.google.com/100132233764003563318/posts/jVuXSAXj3rL)

Comment: It turns out that I had forgotten to add that line in this version. I had included that in versions prior to uploading to Chrome Store, and am not sure how I neglected it this time. I know that it hadn't made a difference before, and the app still had no idea which would be accepted.

Comment: @chris: Does this answer solve your problem? Could you accept it?

Comment: Probably not. Kiosk Mode as I have found out *most likely* only works for true Apps. Not these simple extensions that only function as bookmarks essentially. I haven't tested lately, probably should. I ended up just using Supervised Users on ChromeOS to lock down our Kiosk systems.

Comment: That was not in the original version which is what my response was based on. The question was later updated to have the full manifest being used.

Comment: I'm sorry to report that the question is dead.
I no longer work for the company, and the idea was abandoned long ago. I did end up getting it to work, but I do not remember the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure that in order to use as a kiosk application, you must upload as public or unlisted.