# ChromeBox app does not use proxy settings in Kiosk mode

Tags: proxy, google-chrome-app, kiosk, kiosk-mode

Using a chrome application on a Chromebox that displays a web page in Kiosk mode, the URL is not found in enterprise because the proxy settings are not taken into account. It works fine in regular browser without kiosk mode.

I may have missed a configuration step ?
Or is it possible in the application code to specify / force the usage of a proxy ?

(Can be tested with 'Kiosk' application : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kiosk/afhcomalholahplbjhnmahkoekoijban)

Comment: Have not found any proxy API for apps. It exists for extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer on this [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640198/why-is-this-google-chrome-hosted-app-invalid-for-kiosk-mode). According to this [support page](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/3316168?hl=en), apps can't be added as kiosk apps when they are published privately. Just make sure that you're following the steps outlined [here](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/3134673?hl=en) and [here](https://docs.appspace.com/appspace/5.9/device/chromebox/chrome-device-management/) to enable Kiosk mode correctly.